# How to create symbolic link in PHP pointing to subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

I need to create sub domains with Magento.

I have followed the steps in:

http://www.crucialwebhost.com/kb/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/#sub-domain-method

After the 7th step I have tried to access the URL sub.sitename.com
but it gives error message:

```
/var/www/sub.sitename.com/app/Mage.php was not found
```

It has been creating shortcuts I have check this one using FTP connection.

Please help me, let me know what to do next .

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you did not create the link the right way?

```
ln -s [TARGET DIRECTORY OR FILE] ./[SHORTCUT]
```

In your example i see:

```
ln -s ../public_html/app ./app
ln -s ../public_html/errors ./errors
ln -s ../public_html/includes ./includes
ln -s ../public_html/js ./js
ln -s ../public_html/lib ./lib
ln -s ../public_html/media ./media
ln -s ../public_html/skin ./skin
ln -s ../public_html/var ./var
```

Try not to use ../ :

```
ln -s /public_html/app ./app
ln -s /public_html/errors ./errors
ln -s /public_html/includes ./includes
ln -s /public_html/js ./js
ln -s /public_html/lib ./lib
ln -s /public_html/media ./media
ln -s /public_html/skin ./skin
ln -s /public_html/var ./var
```

Hope it helps.